# Flutter Provider package reinitializes when saving in VSCode

Tags: flutter

I have a simple app with which I am using the Provider package. Within the class using Provider, I fetch some data online and build a collection.  I then use it on a couple of other screens.  I set up the MultiProvider in main.dart.

```
return MultiProvider(
  providers: [
    ChangeNotifierProvider<UserStationInfoProvider>.value(
      value: UserStationInfoProvider(),
    ),
    ChangeNotifierProvider<UserStationList>.value(
      value: UserStationList(),
    ),
  ],
  child: MaterialApp(
```

Within UserStationList is list of the items I am getting online and an integer that indicates which one was selected by the user.  I use this data in a couple of screens.  The problem comes when I have an emulator up and I make a code change and save the code. The code in main.dart is run again. 
 The providers are set up again and I lose my collection of items and my integer that holds the item that was selected.  If I don't fetch my data again, then I don't have any data and regardless of whether I fetch the data or not, I lose the value in the integer.

Is there any way around this?  I'm starting to think that maybe I'm using Provider in a way that it shouldn't be used.

This has been working well.  Once I get into my

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That happens because you are creating your state directly inside the build method.

It is anti-pattern, and will make you loose your state when the widget rebuilds (which happens on hot reload but not only that).

`provider` also explicitly states that we should **not** use the `.value` constructor to create a value, and instead use the default constructor.

So you can change your:

```
ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
  value: MyModel()
)
```

into:

```
ChangeNotifierProvider(
  builder: (_) => MyModel()
)
```